# C# Sqlite Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, sqlite, foreign-keys, uwp

I have a problem with my code, I want turn on the foreign keys but I got error messages.
I am using SQLitePCL installed with nuget, and I added SQLite for UWP as reference.

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
            {
                var parameter = e.Parameter as string; 

                if (parameter != null && parameter.Equals("new"))
                {
                    SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("New.db"); 
                         string Head_Create = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Head
                                                                (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL
                                                                , A TEXT
                                                                , B TEXT
                                                                , C TEXT
                                                                , D TEXT
                                                                , E TEXT                                               
                                                                );";

ISQLiteStatement cnStatement_Head1 = dbConnection.Prepare(Head_Create);
cnStatement_Head1.Step();

string SQLite_Metrados_Head_Pragma = @"PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON";             
ISQLiteStatement cnStatement_Head2 = dbConnection.Prepare(SQLite_Metrados_Head_Pragma);
cnStatement_Head2.Step();
```

I got the error in the line:

```
ISQLiteStatement cnStatement_Head2 = dbConnection.Prepare(SQLite_Metrados_Head_Pragma);
```

> Additional information: Unable to prepare the sql statement: PRAGMA
>   foreign_keys = ON Details: near "PRAGMA foreign_keys": syntax error

It seems like a syntax error but I am writing the correct string for foreign keys dude, I was testing with the string:

```
@"PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;"
```

But it get error too.

Any help with my string (or the correct string for turn on the foreign keys in sqlite) is appreciated.

Comment: Thx for your reply, my SQLitePCL version is 3.8.7.2 and the database is created using CREATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
near "PRAGMA foreign_keys": syntax error
```

The thing quoted after "near" should be a single word. So in this case, the space character is not actually a normal space character but something else, such as a non-breaking space.

Comment: Correct! This is the only way I could replicate the issue :-) `string SQLite_Metrados_Head_Pragma = "PRAGMA^foreign_keys = ON".Replace('^', (char)0XA0);` Actually, even with an older sqlite version (not supporting foreign keys) no exception is thrown.